# Regularity of delta distribution

Tags: dirac-delta

What is the regularity of the Delta distribution?
I found a claim stating that for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\delta(x) \in H^{-s}$ with $s>n/2$ but I could not find any reliable reference for it.